# C++: 1-What is a different between define a variable to keep and print the answer ,2-and just print the answer?

Tags: c++, printing, difference

What is the difference between :

```
#define PI 3.14
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r;
    float area;
    cout << "Enter the radius:";
    cin>>r;
    area=r*r*PI;
    cout << area << endl;
}
```

and

```
#define PI 3.14
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r;
    cout << "Enter the radius:";
    cin>>r;
    cout << r*r*PI <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please post any code as text in the question rather than images.

Comment: please one question per question. And please post an actual question not just a link

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your case it changes nothing.

You can always use godbolt to take a look at the asm.

https://godbolt.org/z/wkFHM5

As you can see

```
area=r*r*PI;
cout << area << endl;
```

produces the same code as

```
cout << r*r*PI << endl;
```

The intermediate variable is a way and storing data that you want to reuse that is all.